# Url.Action() causes System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

I added e-mail verification to ASP.NET identity model within a standard ASP.NET MVC project. The following line causes an AccessViolationException:

```
callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", confirmModel, Request.Url.Scheme);
```

**UPDATE:** **As unexplainable as the problem was it disappeared. I will try to figure out what made it go away. To my concern I am not aware of any dramatic changes to the solution.**

The complete account controller method for registering users looks like that:

```
// POST: /Account/Register
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);

            string callbackUrl;
            try
            {
                string requestScheme = Request.Url.Scheme;
                object confirmModel = new { userId = user.Id, code = code };
                callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", confirmModel, Request.Url.Scheme); // TODO: Fails somehow!
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                callbackUrl = "https://localhost:43000/Account/ConfirmEmail?userid=" + user.Id + "&code=" + code;
            }

            await
                UserManager.SendEmailAsync(
                        userId: user.Id,
                        subject: "Verify it's you",
                        body: "Please confirm your email address by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

            return View("CheckYourEmail");
        }

        AddErrors(result);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Unfortunately there is no inner exception or anything useful.

The catch() block solves the problem as a workaround.
But I am really curious what is going wrong here.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the exact text of the entire output of `ex.ToString()` in to your question?

Comment: What's the stack trace look like on the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting it object confirmModel = ..., use "dynamic confirmModel = ..." and see if that fixes it.